# Display stars from a value

Tags: html, css

I've followed this awesome tutorial for achieve a stars rating system : [Tutorial](http://voidcanvas.com/make-simple-star-rating-by-radio-buttons-using-css/) [Demo](http://www.voidcanvas.com/demo/?art=http://voidcanvas.com/make-simple-star-rating-by-radio-buttons-using-css&demoid=4029star-rating#.VUoAZpNdswo)

This is fully working and i've did the necessary for save the stars form into MySQL table.
Now i would like to display the stars value registered in my table with the stars system from the tutorial. Exemple `$starsvalue = 4;` then it shows 4 colored stars and the last one empty.

Currently i don't know how to display the stars with the result of `$starsvalue`. Any help is very welcome.

**Form used :**

```
echo "<form id=\"ratingsForm\" name=\"starsrating\" method=\"POST\">";
                echo "<div class=\"stars\">";
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"star\" class=\"star-1\" id=\"star-1\" value=\"1\" onclick=\"this.form.submit()\"/>";
                echo "<label class=\"star-1\" for=\"star-1\">1</label>";
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"star\" class=\"star-2\" id=\"star-2\" value=\"2\" onclick=\"this.form.submit()\"/>";
                echo "<label class=\"star-2\" for=\"star-2\">2</label>";
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"star\" class=\"star-3\" id=\"star-3\" value=\"3\" onclick=\"this.form.submit()\"/>";
                echo "<label class=\"star-3\" for=\"star-3\">3</label>";
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"star\" class=\"star-4\" id=\"star-4\" value=\"4\" onclick=\"this.form.submit()\"/>";
                echo "<label class=\"star-4\" for=\"star-4\">4</label>";
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"star\" class=\"star-5\" id=\"star-5\" value=\"5\" onclick=\"this.form.submit()\"/>";
                echo "<label class=\"star-5\" for=\"star-5\">5</label>";
                echo "<span></span>";
                echo "</div>";

                echo "<div style=\"visibility:hidden\"><Input type=submit name=\"choix\" value=\"Valider\"></div>";

                echo "</form>";
```

**CSS used :**

```
   body {
      padding: 50px;
    }
    form .stars {
      background: url("stars.png") repeat-x 0 0;
      width: 150px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    form .stars input[type="radio"] {
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    }
    form .stars input[type="radio"].star-5:checked ~ span {
      width: 100%;
    }
    form .stars input[type="radio"].star-4:checked ~ span {
      width: 80%;
    }
    form .stars input[type="radio"].star-3:checked ~ span {
      width: 60%;
    }
    form .stars input[type="radio"].star-2:checked ~ span {
      width: 40%;
    }
    form .stars input[type="radio"].star-1:checked ~ span {
      width: 20%;
    }
    form .stars label {
      display: block;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      margin: 0!important;
      padding: 0!important;
      text-indent: -999em;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 10;
      background: transparent!important;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    form .stars label:hover ~ span {
      background-position: 0 -30px;
    }
    form .stars label.star-5:hover ~ span {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
    form .stars label.star-4:hover ~ span {
      width: 80% !important;
    }
    form .stars label.star-3:hover ~ span {
      width: 60% !important;
    }
    form .stars label.star-2:hover ~ span {
      width: 40% !important;
    }
    form .stars label.star-1:hover ~ span {
      width: 20% !important;
    }
    form .stars span {
      display: block;
      width: 0;
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 30px;
      background: url("stars.png") repeat-x 0 -60px;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-width 0.5s;
      -moz-transition: -moz-width 0.5s;
      -ms-transition: -ms-width 0.5s;
      -o-transition: -o-width 0.5s;
      transition: width 0.5s;
    }
```

*** UPDATE ***

Trying Raty as suggested and i don't manage to make appear the stars. The CSS and JS files seems at the good places. I think i don't understand how to configure it like set the stars images folder and other parameters

I don't know where i'm supposed to copy thoses codes very common on raty's webpage  ?

$('div').raty({
  number: function() {
    return $(this).attr('data-number');
  }
});

My code :

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./raty/lib/jquery.raty.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./raty/stylesheets/labs.css" media="screen" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="./raty/vendor/jquery.js"></script><script src="./raty/lib/jquery.raty.js"></script>
    <script src="./raty/javascripts/labs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

<article>

    <div class="body">
        <h1>Default</h1>

        <p>You need just to have a <code>div</code> to build the Raty.</p>

        <div id="default"></div>
        <div class="highlight"><pre><span class="nt">&lt;div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</span>
        </pre></div>
        <div class="highlight"><pre><span class="nx">$</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="s1">'div'</span><span class="p">).</span><span class="nx">raty</span><span class="p">();</span>
        </pre></div>
```

Comment: replace the class, id with this class = <?php echo "star-".$starvalue; ?>

Comment: @RajatModi This will show the five stars empty and if you put your cursor on it it colors the first 4 stars. It's almost that i just need it shows the 4 stars colored directly, without the need to place the cursor on it.

Comment: Well in that case I will always recommend to use this http://wbotelhos.com/raty it is super easy and flexible.

Comment: @RajatModi Thanks for the link. It sounds like super easy, i must be realy bad because it has been over an hour now i'm trying to set it up and it wont works... it wont shows the stars

Comment: Post your code in the question so I can take a look...

Comment: checking the code and let you know really soon.... :)

Comment: I have updated my answer review it let me know if any confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the tutorial, if the radio button is ***checked*** so you will see the yellow star.

```
$starsvalue=4;
echo "<form id=\"ratingsForm\" name=\"starsrating\" method=\"POST\">";
echo "<div class=\"stars\">";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"star\" class=\"star-$i\" id=\"star-$i\" value=\"$i\" ";
    if ($i === $starsvalue) {
        echo " checked='checked' ";
    }
    echo "onclick=\"this.form.submit()\"/>";
    echo "<label class=\"star-$i\" for=\"star-$i\">$i</label>";
}
echo "<span></span>";
echo "</div>";

echo "<div style=\"visibility:hidden\"><Input type=submit name=\"choix\" value=\"Valider\"></div>";

echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Works perfectly ! I've just changed <code>echo "onclick=\"return false;\"/>"; </code>. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Here is the source code How I make with Raty.

Step 1: http://github.com/wbotelhos/raty/archive/2.7.0.zip I downloaded it and after extraction I rename the folder to raty.

Step 2: I placed html file just besides of this raty folder.

```
<link href="raty/demo/stylesheets/labs.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="raty/lib/jquery.raty.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="raty/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="raty/lib/jquery.raty.js"></script>
<script src="raty/demo/javascripts/labs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div data-number="5"></div>

<script>
$('div').raty({
    number:$(this).attr('data-number'),
    half     : true,
    path     : null,
    starHalf : 'raty/demo/images/star-half-mono.png',
    starOff  : 'raty/lib/images/star-off.png',
    starOn   : 'raty/lib/images/star-on.png'
});

</script>
```

maybe labs.css and labs.js are not useful but as of now I just copied it so take care of that too.

**EDIT**

For selected value suppose `$starvalue = 4`

```
<script>
$('div').raty({
    number:$(this).attr('data-number'),
    half     : true,
    path     : null,
    starHalf : 'raty/demo/images/star-half-mono.png',
    starOff  : 'raty/lib/images/star-off.png',
    starOn   : 'raty/lib/images/star-on.png',
    score: <?php echo $starvalue; ?>
});

</script>
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! I've added to it readOnly and now i understand how it works it's perfect. Thank you !